# How can I post a message in Slack as email

Tags: slack-api, slack

I want to create an integration that will post an email to a given channel in Slack, but I don't want to use the official Email app. What should I do to Slack identify my message as an email and apply the same styles?

Comment: I think they intentionally limit this email function to their own email app, as it's a premium feature. [Clubble](https://slack.com/apps/A08MWL06Q-clubbleio) is an alternative.

Comment: There are many approaches. A very simple one would be to use a custom command like "/email recipient-email message" and attach it to a php script that sends "message" to "recipient-email". And you could setup another php scripts that receives emails and posts them into a Slack channel.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use the official Email app but maybe you'll use an unofficial app ;)

[MailClark](http://mailclark.ai) allows you to send emails to & from Slack.